# Cannot compile Typescript Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, typescript, npm, jasmine

```
throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
      ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)

api/public/reports/api-report.spec.ts (1,46): Cannot find module './api-report'. (2307)
...
20 lines of different modules not found
src/api/public/reports/api-report.spec.ts (134,17): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
```

^ Above errors when attempting to do "npm test" with test as "jasmine-ts /folder/*.spec.ts"

Ubuntu 16.04

I've looked extensively, reinstalled node, npm, nvm, jasmine. Looked at my code. No clue what it could be.

Comment: it might be something that leads you to a better place :) I found using [typescript together with webpack](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#webpack) a much much much more enjoyable experience :)  
EDIT:  
you do need to do `npm i -D @types/[module]` for your dependencies though

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't find the type definitions for node, I can only assume that you are working on a node app, and do not have the type definitions installed. You'll need to:

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

...and then reference this file with a triple slash directive.

See the documentation on [type definitions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html) and [references](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html). It sounds like you'll need to do this for jasmine as well.

It also sounds like you might not be importing other modules appropriately, but it would be impossible to tell without seeing the code.